# When moving to a new enclose, any gotchas with ZFS?

Tags: ubuntu, migration, zfs

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server that has an attached ZFS Zpool of four drives and  a caching drive. The entire thing (drives, motherboard, all of it) is being moved to a new enclosure that'll allow me for better future expansion.

I did some research but I couldn't find any explicit information about such a transfer so I was wondering if there are any gotchas that I should keep an eye out for? The only one I can think of is whether or not it matters that I keep the all the drives attached to the same SATA ports or if it doesn't matter?

Here's my Zpool config:

```
config:

NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
Storage     ONLINE       0     0     0
  raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
cache
  sdb       ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: When you setup your pool did you use GUIDs, labels, or the older `/dev/sdN`?  Are you doing anything unusual with full disk encryption or anything?  If you set things up  properly with predictable device names it should 'just work'.

Comment: Updated with more information. I'm not doing full-disk encryption. My setup is pretty bog-standard. But I set this up a while ago and "properly" is an assumption I'm not willing to make. :D